# How to force Foundation to go 2 columns first before going full width?

Tags: responsive-design, grid, zurb-foundation, responsive

I'm using Foundation for our website and there's a section where there are 3 boxes / columns per row. As in:

[image]

CODE:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">[BOX]</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">[BOX]</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">[BOX]</div>
</div>
```

Now when the browser is resized to about 1023px, each column suddenly changes to full width, as in:

[image]

..even though there is still some space on the right to go 2-columns first.

How do I make it so that Foundation goes to 2-columns first at a certain media query size before going full-width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that may find this helpful:

```
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-3">
    <div class="columns">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Large-up-3** means on large screen, the columns would be 3,

**Medium-up-2** means on medium screen, the columns would be 2,

**Small-up-1** means on small screen, the column would be 1 only.

You can change the numbers as per how many columns you want displayed.

(Foundation 5 has this update.)